# Why is array seemingly empty after the loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, debugging, javascript-objects

```js
function par(idF, idM) {
  this.IDOvna = idM;
  this.IDOvce = idF;

}



function breeding() {
  let idOvce = [];
  let brOvce = [];
  let mesecOvce = [];
  let godinaOvce = [];
  let istorija1 = [];
  let istorija2 = [];

  let idOvna = [];
  let brOvna = [];
  let mesecOvna = [];
  let godinaOvna = [];

  let y = 0;
  let o = 0;
  let parovi = [];
  let c = 0;
  fetch("http://localhost/ovce/ovce.json")
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      for (let i = 0; i < data.ovce.length; i++) {
        idOvce[i] = data.ovce[i].id;
        brOvce[i] = data.ovce[i].broj;
        mesecOvce[i] = data.ovce[i].mesec;
        godinaOvce[i] = data.ovce[i].godina;
        istorija1[i] = data.ovce[i].istorija1;
        istorija2[i] = data.ovce[i].istorija2;
      }
    });
  fetch("http://localhost/ovce/ovnovi.json")
    .then(function(resp1) {
      return resp1.json();
    })
    .then(function(data1) {
      console.log(data1);
      for (let g = 0; g < data1.ovnovi.length; g++) {
        idOvna[g] = data1.ovnovi[g].id;
        brOvna[g] = data1.ovnovi[g].broj;
        mesecOvna[g] = data1.ovnovi[g].mesec;
        godinaOvna[g] = data1.ovnovi[g].godina;
      }
    });

  while (o < idOvna.length) {
    y = 0;
    while (y < idOvce.length) {
      if (istorija1[y] != 0) {
        if ((istorija2[y] != idOvna[o]) && (istorija2[istorija1[y]] != idOvna[o])) {
          parovi[c] = new par(idOvce[y], idOvna[o]);
          c++;
        }
      } else {
        parovi[c] = new par(idOvce[y], idOvna[o]);
        c++;
      }
      y++;
    }
    o++;
  }
  console.log(parovi);
  return parovi;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sheepify</title>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="breeding()"> Breeding </button>
</body>

</html>
```

In javascript, i have a loop running and afterwards the pairs array which should be populated is empty.

```
function pair(idF, idM) {
  this.IDOvna = idM;
  this.IDOvce = idF;
}

function problem() {
  let y = 0;
  let o = 0;
  let pairs = [];
  let c = 0;

  //id, id1, history1, history2 are arrays which are populated from the json files using fetch.

  while (o < id.length) {
    y = 0;
    while (y < id1.length) {
      if (history1[y] != 0) {
        if ((history2[y] != id[o]) && (history2[history1[y]] != id[o])) {
          pairs[c] = new pair(id1[y], id[o]);
          c++;
        }
      } else {
        pairs[c] = new pair(id1[y], id[o]);
        c++;
      }
      y++;
    }
    o++;
  }
  console.log(pairs);
  console.log(pairs.length);
}
```

When i run a debugger the array is populated and everything is fine, but when i execute the function on button click or through a console, it just returns an empty array. What could be causing this problem?
EDIT: I accidentally pasted the pair function inside the problem function, which isn't the case. I have moved it out now. And changed leght to length as suggested.
EDIT2: Here is the full code, sorry about the variable names, they are in Serbian.

Comment: It would help if you included the values of all the arrays you're accessing. Also, the code would be easier to read if you used `for` loops instead of `while`, and `pairs.push()`.

Comment: Are you sure the arrays contain values that fit the criteria used to add pairs to the array?

Comment: The `pairs` variable is local to the function. How do you use it in the button click?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: `fetch()` is asynchronous. Are you sure the fetch has completed before you run this function?

Comment: You need to run this in the `.then()` callback of `fetch()`. Otherwise the arrays won't be populated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: I don't think fetch is the problem here since all the variables populated using fetch are fine, pairs array doesn't have anything to do with fetch.

Comment: Put `console.log(JSON.stringify(id), JSON.stringify(id1), JSON.stringify(history1), JSON.stringify(history2))` before the `while` loop. Make sure you use `JSON.stringify` so you see the arrays at that time; if you just log the arrays, the console updates when the arrays are filled in.

Comment: You say that the variables are all populated, but you could be wrong. Post the actual code.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback i will try adding the console.log statement you suggested. Also, i have posted the actual code in the snippet, but the variable names are in Serbian, so I hope it helps.

Comment: It's exactly what we said. The loop is not in the `.then()` functions, so the arrays have not been populated.

Comment: So what you are saying is that all the variables populated in the promise or `.then()` of the fetch lose their value outside the `.then()` section?

Comment: They don't lose their values, the values haven't been set yet. Do you understand how asynchronous functions work?

Comment: `fetch()` returns *before* the callbacks have been executed.

Comment: Did you read the question I linked to above?

Comment: Oooh, okay now i get it. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop that processes the arrays is outside the fetch callback functions, so it doesn't wait for the arrays to be populated. See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).

You can make your function `async` and use `await` to wait for them.

Note also that the code that calls this will need to use `await` or `.then()` to get the returned `parovi` array. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

```js
async function breeding() {
  let idOvce = [];
  let brOvce = [];
  let mesecOvce = [];
  let godinaOvce = [];
  let istorija1 = [];
  let istorija2 = [];

  let idOvna = [];
  let brOvna = [];
  let mesecOvna = [];
  let godinaOvna = [];

  let y = 0;
  let o = 0;
  let parovi = [];
  let c = 0;
  await fetch("http://localhost/ovce/ovce.json")
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      for (let i = 0; i < data.ovce.length; i++) {
        idOvce[i] = data.ovce[i].id;
        brOvce[i] = data.ovce[i].broj;
        mesecOvce[i] = data.ovce[i].mesec;
        godinaOvce[i] = data.ovce[i].godina;
        istorija1[i] = data.ovce[i].istorija1;
        istorija2[i] = data.ovce[i].istorija2;
      }
    });
  await fetch("http://localhost/ovce/ovnovi.json")
    .then(function(resp1) {
      return resp1.json();
    })
    .then(function(data1) {
      console.log(data1);
      for (let g = 0; g < data1.ovnovi.length; g++) {
        idOvna[g] = data1.ovnovi[g].id;
        brOvna[g] = data1.ovnovi[g].broj;
        mesecOvna[g] = data1.ovnovi[g].mesec;
        godinaOvna[g] = data1.ovnovi[g].godina;
      }
    });

  while (o < idOvna.length) {
    y = 0;
    while (y < idOvce.length) {
      if (istorija1[y] != 0) {
        if ((istorija2[y] != idOvna[o]) && (istorija2[istorija1[y]] != idOvna[o])) {
          parovi[c] = new par(idOvce[y], idOvna[o]);
          c++;
        }
      } else {
        parovi[c] = new par(idOvce[y], idOvna[o]);
        c++;
      }
      y++;
    }
    o++;
  }
  console.log(parovi);
  return parovi;
}

function par(idF, idM) {
  this.IDOvna = idM;
  this.IDOvce = idF;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sheepify</title>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="breeding()"> Breeding </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

how are you using this `problem` function within the fetch?

If you are using int outside the fetch its totaly normal, your arrays will be empty.

Edit:

As you have post the fetch method, you need to put all your while loop un the last then, when you are populating the data, because fetch is async =/
Since you have two fetch, and both are populating the array's you need to do the second in the last `then` of the first `fetch`. And finaly you can do your `while`  loop in last `then` of your second `fetch`.
It may be more clearner using async await method.

```
function par(idF, idM) {
    this.IDOvna = idM;
    this.IDOvce = idF;
}
  
  
  
function breeding() {
    let idOvce = [];
    let brOvce = [];
    let mesecOvce = [];
    let godinaOvce = [];
    let istorija1 = [];
    let istorija2 = [];

    let idOvna = [];
    let brOvna = [];
    let mesecOvna = [];
    let godinaOvna = [];

    let y = 0;
    let o = 0;
    let parovi = [];
    let c = 0;
    fetch("http://localhost/ovce/ovce.json")
    .then(function(resp) {
    return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.ovce.length; i++) {
        idOvce[i] = data.ovce[i].id;
        brOvce[i] = data.ovce[i].broj;
        mesecOvce[i] = data.ovce[i].mesec;
        godinaOvce[i] = data.ovce[i].godina;
        istorija1[i] = data.ovce[i].istorija1;
        istorija2[i] = data.ovce[i].istorija2;
    }

    fetch("http://localhost/ovce/ovnovi.json")
    .then(function(resp1) {
    return resp1.json();
    })
    .then(function(data1) {
        console.log(data1);
        for (let g = 0; g < data1.ovnovi.length; g++) {
            idOvna[g] = data1.ovnovi[g].id;
            brOvna[g] = data1.ovnovi[g].broj;
            mesecOvna[g] = data1.ovnovi[g].mesec;
            godinaOvna[g] = data1.ovnovi[g].godina;

            while (o < idOvna.length) {
            y = 0;
            while (y < idOvce.length) {
                if (istorija1[y] != 0) {
                if ((istorija2[y] != idOvna[o]) && (istorija2[istorija1[y]] != idOvna[o])) {
                    parovi[c] = new par(idOvce[y], idOvna[o]);
                    c++;
                }
                } else {
                parovi[c] = new par(idOvce[y], idOvna[o]);
                c++;
                }
                y++;
            }
            o++;
            }
            console.log(parovi);
            return parovi;
        }
        });
    });
    

}
```

Comment: In his code he right that the arrays are populated using a fetch on a json file

Comment: Everything is inside the `problem` function, I just didn't think it was necessary to include the fetch part because it wasn't relevant to the issue, since the data assignment is working fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). I've posted a similar comment for you.

Comment: I think the fetch is the key of your problem,

Comment: Thank's @Barmar , it's hard when we start, plenty of question and i can't ask them, so ... yes i'm using the Answer area =/ sorry

Comment: @Barmar if he think's this fetch is working great, can he populate by hand the arrays and share for us to check ? (please comment this haha )

Comment: I have, I have shared the full code.

Comment: I edit my edit if you want to read, @Barmar response is better unsing async await method, but if you want to keep with the then method is like that